# Create EOI login in SINP with ECA status as "NO" and Express Entry profile as "NO"?

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry, pr

My query is, I've acquired my IELTS but the ECA (Education Credential Assesment) is not yet complete.

Can I proceed to create an EOI profile in SINP with ECA status as "NO" and with Express Entry profile as "NO"?

Is it mandatory to create an Express Entry profile?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be selected in future Saskatchewan draws if you do not have ECA.

And you can create EOI without an Express Entry profile. This is called OID stream.

However, if you can create an Express Entry account, I strongly recommend to do it. This will direct you to SINP-EE stream which has way faster federal process.

OID (Occupation in-Demand) takes 17 months in federal process, however SINP-EE takes only 6 months.

Worth to note that OID applications are processed a few weeks faster than SINP-EE in provincial process, However, adding the time needed to process them both in federal, OID is about one year slower overall!

Comment: Thanks @Iman for detailed information. *What I mean is my ECA process is in progress. So till the time it completes, i want to create SINP profile. Later when my ECA process is completed, I will further update it to "Yes"* - **as suggested by one of the Agent :)**. But in this case, if there is a risk that my profile will not be selected in future Draws, I don't want to do that.

Comment: @Cdarji Yes, if I were you, I would have waited for ECA to come, so I can create an EE profile and continue with SINP-EE cause if you submit an EOI without EE profile number, and you get ITA, you are forced to continue with OID which is a slow paper-based stream. So if you think you will get that in near future (assuming WES does that in 6 weeks), just wait for it. I know you are a little bit worried about your NOC to be eliminated,

Comment: @Cdarji but don't be since the NOCs that have participated in recent draws are a lot, and they are picking only few for each NOC, meaning there is good chance for your NOC to be in-demand for a long time comparing to their old practice. if you find my answer useful please mark it as accepted answer. Good luck.

Comment: @Cdarji you got me wrong, it is not that you wont be ever drawn again because you said you din’t have ECA at the moment. I am saying : SINP only selects those who have ECA. You change it to YES you will be drawn!

Comment: Okay.. So you mean, I should create an EOI profile with ECA ="NO" for now. Is it?

Comment: @Cdarji No, wait for ECA to come because even if you get ITA it will be OID which doesn’t worth it! (One year longer! Remember!?)

Comment: Alright.. Thank you so much Iman..!!